# Quadratic Variation of $X$ defined by a differential equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $X = (X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be a stochastic process defined by
$$
d X_t = 3dt + 2 \sqrt X_t d B_t,
$$
where $B$ is a standard Brownian motion.
What is its quadratic variation? I have a subtle intuition that is defined by $d\langle X,X\rangle_t = 2\sqrt X_t d t$, but I do not know how to justify it correctly.

Comment: How is the process $X$ defined? It seems that there is missing an "$=$" somewhere.

Comment: completely right, so sorry. Now is correct

Comment: The quadratic variation process of the finite variation part is zero. For the quadratic variation of the Ito integral you can see a proof here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2818913/quadratic-variation-of-ito-integral/3937161#3937161

Answer (score 0):

The quadratic variation of the process is given by
$$\mathrm d \langle X,X\rangle_t=4 |X_t|\mathrm dt.
$$
In general, for processes $Z_t=\int_0^tH_s\mathrm dX_t$ and $Q_t=\int_0^tK_s\mathrm dY_t$ holds
$$\mathrm d \langle Z,Q\rangle_t=H_tK_t\mathrm d\langle X,Y\rangle_t,
$$
for $X,\ Y$ semimartingales and $H,\ K$ adapted càglàd processes.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Why should this be a comment? It's the answer to the question.